# In Java, class OneDimArrayMethods, method seqSearch, I'm getting a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java

I know all the potential causes for this error, but I can't see the problem. The error is on line 17. It's probably something simple, but I could use another pair of eyes on this, thanks!!

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class TestSeqSearch
    {
       static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          int[] intList = new int[10];
          int number;
          int index;

          System.out.println("Line 10: Enter "
                         + intList.length + " integers.");

          for (index = 0; index < intList.length; index++)
              intList[index] = console.nextInt();

          System.out.println();

          System.out.print("Line 14: Enter the number "
                         + "to be searched: ");
          number = console.nextInt();
          System.out.println();

          index = OneDimArrayMethods.seqSearch(intList,
                                 intList.length, number);   //Line 17

          if (index  != -1)
              System.out.println("Line 19: " + number
                               + " is found at position "
                               + index);
          else
              System.out.println("Line 21: " + number
                             + " is not in the list.");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Does the class `OneDimArrayMethods` exist?

Comment: And I just realized I'm stupid! Haha, thanks! Please excuse my inexperience.

Comment: It looks like that class you took it from github, right? The OneDimArrayMethods class.

Comment: No, not from github, it's in my book for my Intro to Software Dev class. We skipped ahead a few chapters, and I wasn't paying close enough attention and didn't realize OneDimArrayMethods wasn't a predefined class. It even says so right in the text, now that I've reread it.